# Nuxt3 useFetch dynamic request not working

Tags: nuxt3

I want to send multiple requests with different url parameters like a pagination feature. I found that `useAsyncData` works well but `useFetch` doesn't work. Is this a bug in nuxt codebase or not?

the codesandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/little-fog-y5gevk?file=%2Fapp.vue&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A33%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A1%7D%5D

```js
<script setup>
const count = ref(1);

// doesn't work
// const { data, refresh } = await useFetch(`/api/hello`, {
//   query: { count: count.value },
// });

// it works
const { data, refresh } = await useAsyncData("hello", () =>
  $fetch("/api/hello", {
    query: { count: count.value },
  })
);

function add() {
  count.value++;
  refresh();
}
</script>

<template>
  <NuxtExampleLayout example="composables/use-fetch">
    <div>
      Fetch result:
      <pre class="text-left"><code>{{ data }}</code></pre>
      <NButton @click="count++"> + </NButton>

      <NButton @click="add">add</NButton>
    </div>
  </NuxtExampleLayout>
</template>
```